# single node js server to answer bunch of sites

Tags: node.js

I have created the following code to answer about 10 sites and multiple function on them
the problem is if the sites have more than 50 users online at the same time the cpu usage will hit 100% and crashes the server
can anyonve give me any solution?

```
var app = require('http').createServer()
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');
var moment = require('moment')();
moment .zone("+-8:00");
//moment.date() dat of month
//moment.month() dat of month


var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection;
// MYSQL CONFIG
connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '',
    user: '',
    password: '@@',
    database: 'nodejs'
});

// listen port 8084
// please open this port on firewall and iptables
app.listen(8084);
var xsocket = io.listen(app);
console.log('Listen On Port 8084  ' + connection);
var dblists = [];
var users = {};
var domains_tmp;

// get db list
connection.query('SELECT db_name, domain_name  FROM tbl_dblist order by id asc ;', function (err, rows, fields) {
    //  console.log('Connection result error ' + err);
    //  console.log('no of records is ' + rows.length);
    // send data to all servers
    var count = -1;
    rows.forEach(function (entry) {
        count++;
        dblists[entry["domain_name"]] = {
            dbname: entry["db_name"], cn: mysql.createConnection({
                host: '',
                user: '',
                password: '',
                database: entry["db_name"]
            })
        };
    })
    // console.log("DBLIST : ", dblists);
});

// handle request from clients
function handler(conn,conn_id) {

    if(!conn.connected)
        return;
    var i = String(users[conn_id].domain);
    // when db for domain not defined

    try {
        if (i.length <= 0 || i == "undefined")
            return;
        if (dblists[i].dbname.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        dblists[i].cn.query('SELECT max(id) as id  FROM tbl_transaction  ;', function (err, maxrow, fields) {
            // send data to Connected Client
            if (maxrow.length > 0) {
                //console.log("length ",maxrow.length);
                if (maxrow[0].id > users[conn_id].maxrows) {
                    var last_id1 = maxrow[0].id;
                    var last_id = users[conn_id].maxrows;
                    // get last 20 record from table
                    dblists[i].cn.query('SELECT tbl_user.username as who, tbl_transaction.amount,tbl_transaction.date,tbl_transaction.note  FROM '+
                    'tbl_transaction inner join tbl_user on tbl_user.user_id = tbl_transaction.user_id '+
                    '  where tbl_transaction.id > ' + last_id + ' and tbl_transaction.id <=' + last_id1 + ' order by tbl_transaction.id desc limit 20;', function (err, rows, fields) {
                        //  console.log('Connection result error ' + err);
                        //console.log('no of records is ' + rows.length);

                        if(!conn.connected)
                            return;
                        // send data to Connected Client
                        conn.emit("alert", rows);
                        // console.log(rows);
                    });
                    users[conn_id].maxrows = maxrow[0].id;
                }
            }
        });


        // repeat data fetching every 0.5 seconds
        setTimeout(function () {
                handler(conn,conn_id);
            }
            , 1000);
    }
    catch (ex) {

    }
    finally {

    }

}

function mktime() {

    var d = new Date(),
        r = arguments,
        i = 0,
        e = ['Hours', 'Minutes', 'Seconds', 'Month', 'Date', 'FullYear'];

    for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        if (typeof r[i] === 'undefined') {
            r[i] = d['get' + e[i]]();
            r[i] += (i === 3); // +1 to fix JS months.
        } else {
            r[i] = parseInt(r[i], 10);
            if (isNaN(r[i])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Map years 0-69 to 2000-2069 and years 70-100 to 1970-2000.
    r[5] += (r[5] >= 0 ? (r[5] <= 69 ? 2e3 : (r[5] <= 100 ? 1900 : 0)) : 0);

    // Set year, month (-1 to fix JS months), and date.
    // !This must come before the call to setHours!
    d.setFullYear(r[5], r[3] - 1, r[4]);

    // Set hours, minutes, and seconds.
    d.setHours(r[0], r[1], r[2]);

    // Divide milliseconds by 1000 to return seconds and drop decimal.
    // Add 1 second if negative or it'll be off from PHP by 1 second.
    return (d.getTime() / 1e3 >> 0) - (d.getTime() < 0);
}
var i=1654;
function onlineu(socks,connection_online) {
    // die function when the client disconnected
    if (!socks.connected)
        return;
    var return_data = {played:0,total:0,players:0,today:0};

    dblists[connection_online].cn.query('Select sum(playnum) as cnt,sum(amount) as mnt from tbl_user  ;', function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (rows.length > 0) {
            console.log("Rows :", rows[0].cnt, rows[0].mnt);
            return_data.played = rows[0].cnt;
            return_data.total = rows[0].mnt;
        }
    });

    dblists[connection_online].cn.query('select count(user_id) as players from tbl_user  ;', function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (rows.length > 0) {
            console.log("Rows :", rows[0].players);
            return_data.players = rows[0].players;
        }
    });
    var d=moment.date();
    var m=moment.month()+1;
    var  begin=mktime(0,0,0, m, d );
    var end=mktime(23,59,59,m,d);

    dblists[connection_online].cn.query('Select count(id) as cnt,sum(amount) as today from tbl_transaction where date between '+ begin+' and '+ end+'  ;', function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (rows.length > 0) {
            console.log("Rows :", rows[0].today);
            return_data.today = rows[0].today;
        }
    });

    // die function when the client disconnected
    if (!socks.connected)
        return;

    //console.log("online Users", return_data);
    socks.emit("online", return_data);

    setTimeout(function () {
        onlineu(socks,domains_tmp);
    }, 1000);
}
// waiting for client html/js loaded
xsocket.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) {
    query = handshakeData._query;
    if (query.domain == undefined || query.domain.length == 0) {
        console.log("No Domain Specified, Return False");
        return false;
    }
    domains_tmp = query.domain;
    callback(null, true);
});


xsocket.on('connection', function (conn) {
    console.log("New Client : " + conn.id);
    console.log("New Client Domain : " + domains_tmp);
    // Register Client Domain
    users[conn.id] = {id: conn.id, domain: domains_tmp, maxrows: 0};

    onlineu(conn,domains_tmp);
    handler(conn, conn.id);

    conn.on('disconnect', function (conn) {
        // Do Some Thing
    });
});


// end
```

Thanks

Comment: `// repeat data fetching every 0.5 seconds` ... so for each user connected, you're sending two db requests(maybe more, 5?) every half second?

Comment: And then, if one iteration of handler or onlineu takes longer than 500ms to complete, they start to stack up, further increasing the number of simultaneous db requests happening.

Comment: Could you please help me clean it up? i'm not an expert at nodejs

Comment: it's going to take a rewrite of your code because you have to change the way you are looking for data to emit and how you are emitting it. Since i don't know what exactly you are trying to do with this i can't really suggest how to rewrite it. Ideally you should have a single loop looking for data to emit, and then looping over the connections and emitting based on that data. (and only emitting if the information is new)

Comment: The goal is to query some static from database and push to user

Comment: see previous comment.

Comment: Yes ia saw it , how can i loop through connections?

Comment: sorry, i'm not going to explain how to build an array and loop over it.

Comment: i know how to loop an array

Comment: i dont know how to loop the connections

Comment: well, first you would need a collection of connections, in order to loop over them. So, when a connection is created, add it to an array. When a connection is disconnected, remove it from said array.

Comment: so i should emit to that array right?

Comment: Iterate through the array and emit to each one, something like that. You need to read more on Node (or practice coding), pardon the rudeness but you're basically asking us to do the work for you, this is not a good question for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

## Suggested Option

If you want to run multiple node.js applications behind a single IP/server, your best bet is to use a server such as nginx, varnish, ha-proxy to reverse-proxy requests to your application.  Nginx works well in this role and can also be used for caching, SSL termination, spdy, pagespeed and other enhancements.  Recent nginx versions support websockets.

---

## Regarding your application

### You have several issues...

- Your database connections are not pooled, and it looks like you aren't closing them out.

  - You should request an instance from the pool when running a query and release it after
- You are running multiple requests per connecting client in addition to the timed connections.
- You aren't taking advantage of the built in namespaces and channels that socket.io provides.

### Immediate suggestions...

- You should use [connection pooling](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#pooling-connections) for your database connections
- You should abstract out your data access, you may want to consider something like:

  - [orm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/orm)
  - [sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize)
- You should implement a caching scheme (this can be local/in-memory, then cache service, then db lookup) for universally needed data
- You should use socket.io namespaces/rooms for federating messages to other connected users.

  - For multi-process/server setups you'll need to federate messages via a redis adapter or something similar.

### Favor small testable modules and functional paradigms:

- Breaking your code up makes things easier to test.
- Abstracting layers of code makes composition easier
- Favor plain objects and composition over class/oo hierarchies

---

*Note: this is really a hodge-podge of suggestions, because you're issues are very broad, and the approach is fairly sloppy... In general break up your logic into functional modules that can be used to act on objects.  From here you get a better ability to test and compose your application.*